# Does $\sum (-1)^k 2^{1/k}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

How am I supposed to determine the convergence of this series if I only know about the alternating series test and the divergence test?

Comment: Are you talking about the series or the sequence? Neither converges.

Comment: Use the divergence test and compare even and odd values for large $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $k\to\infty$, $\frac 1k\to 0$, $2^{1/k}\to 1$, and $|(-1)^k2^{1/k}|\to 1$.

So if these are the terms of the series, since the terms of the series do not tend to zero, [the series is divergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Limit_of_the_summand).

If these are the partial sums of the series, the even sums tend to $1$ and the odd ones tend to $-1$, so this also does not converge.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about the convergence of the sequence $\{(-1)^k2^{1/k}\}_{k\in \mathbb N}$, you can prove it diverges since it has a subsequence that converges to $1$ and another one that converges to $-1$. Can you identify those subsequences?

**HINT:** $2^{1/k}$ converges to $1$ as $k$ goes to infinity and $(-1)^k$ is either $-1$ or $1$ depending on the parity of $k$.

If you're talking about the convergence of the series

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k2^{1/k}$$

the same argumet shows that it doesn't converges since the its terms doesn't converge (in particular, doesn't converge to zero).